# Kendo Ui Grid Filterable. How can I change filter operator?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Using MVC wrapper, i try to change default filter from "equal" to "contains". I found some examples, but none of them do what I want (or I was wrong to use them...)

Ok, so, this is my code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Portal2.Areas.Coord.Models.ViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.OperationKey).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(c => c.Customer).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(c => c.CarNumber).Filterable(ftb => ftb.UI("CarFilter"));
        columns.Bound(c => c.DriverName).Filterable(ftb => ftb.UI("DriverFilter"));
        columns.Bound(c => c.PhoneNumber).Filterable(ftb => ftb.UI("PhoneFilter"));
    })
    .Filterable(f => f.Extra(false))

    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(r => r
            .Action("Read", "Operations2", new { startTime = (DateTime)ViewBag.startTime, endTime = (DateTime)ViewBag.endTime })
            )
        .PageSize(20)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        )
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 740px" })
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()

    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes(true)
        .ButtonCount(10)
        )
)
```

I have js functions:

```
function Filter(element, atr) {
    var entityGrid = $(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var data = entityGrid.dataSource.data();
    var totalNumber = data.length;
    var drivers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < totalNumber; i++) {
        var currentDataItem = data[i][atr];
        if ($.inArray(currentDataItem, drivers) == -1)
            drivers.push(currentDataItem);
    }
    element.kendoAutoComplete({
        dataSource: drivers
    });
}

function CarFilter(element) {
    Filter(element, "CarNumber")
}
function DriverFilter(element) {
    Filter(element, "DriverName")
}
function PhoneFilter(element) {
    Filter(element, "PhoneNumber")
```

They put all values to helper textbox in each filter. I try this:

```
    columns.Bound(c => c.CarNumber)
        .Filterable(ftb => ftb.UI("CarFilter"))
        .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(c => c.Operator("contains")));
```

but thats work only for `.Filterable(f => f.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))`

```
    .Filterable(filterable => filterable
        .Extra(false)
        .Operators(operators => operators
            .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                .StartsWith("Starts with")
                .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
                .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
            )
        )
    )
```

It doesn't provide the expected result.

Suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

> Kendo Ui Grid Filterable. How can I change filter operator?
>
> ...
>
> try to change default filter from "equal" to "contains"
>
> ...
>
> but works only for .Filterable(f => f.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))

So, how to change filter operators per column:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-column-filter-default-method#mbwcoHyzT02G-SZmRs35YQ

```
columns.Bound(m => m.Field)
    .Filterable(f =>
        f.Operators(
            o => o
                .ForString(s =>
                    s.Clear()
                     .Contains("Contains")
                     .DoesNotContain("Does not contain")
                     .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
                     .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
                     .StartsWith("Starts with")
                     .EndsWith("Ends with ")
                )
        ))
```

Important is to use `s.Clear()` then add the ones you want in the order you want them.

As per linked forum, if the values all match then kendo assumes the defaults and doesn't change the order - so one of them needs a space.